# Is there a way to create Excel relationships using ClosedXML? I tried to do it using a Dataset but it was not implemented in the Excel File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, closedxml

Is there a way to create Excel relationships using ClosedXML? I tried to do it using a Dataset but it was not implemented in the Excel File.

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{                       
     var ds = exportableEntity.GetDataSet();
     wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);


     wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;

     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
          wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
          //Export file                         
     }                       
}
```